# Rewrite with regular expressions

Tags: c#, regex

```
Disposition: form-data; name="To"

ang <ang11@google.com>
-----------------------------7da3d81f160588
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="CC"


-----------------------------7da3d81f160588
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="BCC"


-----------------------------7da3d81f160588
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Subject"

MySubject
-----------------------------7da3d81f160588
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="File"; filename=""<br/>
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


-----------------------------7da3d81f160588
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="cf_loader"

on
-----------------------------7da3d81f160588
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="File"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


-----------------------------7da3d81f160588
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="template_id"


-----------------------------7da3d81f160588
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Body"

MyBody
```

I have written code that get information and writes in an KeyValuePair. As follow:
**Key - Value**
To - ang<\ang11@google.com>
CC - Empty
BCC - Empty
Subject - MySubject
 and etc.
My code is used of class String for this. I need to use regular expressions, but I do not understand them. Help please. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Your current code works, but you want to rewrite it using regular expressions? Why? Also, your formatting seems messed up. Please edit your question, copying the actual text into the edit window, select it and press Ctrl-K to format it "as is".

Comment: @rerun: No, my studies related to the economy. It's just interesting to me. Programming is hobby for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A MIME parser should not be written with regular expressions. The problem is that you require a parser with state and that doesn't really fit regular expressions.

You can however parse parts with regular expressions, so for example:

- First split the MIME body up into parts by splitting on the boundary: `var parts = mime.Split("-----------------------------7da3d81f160588");`;
- Then, extract all the headers using a `part.Split(new { "\r\n" }, 2, StringSplitOptions.None);`;
- Then, parse the headers. This may be done using a regular expression, but it's probably easier to do it like this: `headerLine.Split(new [] { ':' }, 2).Select(p => p.Trim());`.

Now, these separate parts can also be using regular expressions, but this will be a lot harder than a few simple `Split`s.